# How to change PreferenceSettings box color of Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-alertdialog, android-appcompat

I used AppCompat v21 and I want to change color such as on the picture.
Should I add own `AlertDialog` style?

Hex color: #23a397

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You have to set these styles in your activity's theme:

```
<item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/Theme.MyTheme.Dialog</item>
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.MyTheme.Dialog.Alert</item>
```

And create the styles:

```
<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.MyTheme.Dialog.Alert" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
</style>
```

This is an API 21+ solution.

Note that I set both the package prefixed (*android:*) and not-prefixed version to the same color as there were some errors earlier with it. You might not have to set both.

Comment: Thank you. It's working but now I think that `Dialog/AlertDialog` received "fixed style" and adjusts to the text. I was trying to change parent style but without any effect.